# Indentation in three piece comments in javascript

Tags: formatting, comments, filetype-javascript

I use Vim 7.4.2149 and the plugin [pangloss/vim-javascript](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript) for js indentation. I need to get comments like:

```
/*
 *
 */
```

But instead I get:

```
/*
     *
     *
     */
```

I'm not really interested in syntax so I use:

```
syntax off
```

and I tried these settings:

```
formatoptions=croql
comments=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/
```

What should I do to get the comment formatting I'm looking for.

Comment: When default indentation is used ie without plugin, I get the comment formatting I'm looking for.

Comment: You don't need a plugin to indent and fold JavaScript. `:set
autoindent`, and `^T` and `^D` works well for most
languages. Or `:set softtabstop=4 backspace+=indent` if you
don't like `^T` and `^D`. `:set foldmethod=marker
foldmarker={,}` works well enough for folding (template
literals aren't really a big deal). If you don't want syntax, job done.

Comment: Not the answer but autoindent is not that good.

Comment: `vim-javascript` has so far had 149 issues relating to indentation. 150 if you count this one. I'll stick with `'autoindent'`.

Comment: It looks like there was [a fix for this just a few days ago](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript/commit/6d70fab417009adb22062962c853fb8648d044b0). At least, that's what I think from the commit message. Make sure you've got the latest version of `vim-javascript`. You can also make sure this problem [isn't caused by something in your vimrc](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51). If that doesn't fix the problem I suggest you open an issue on their bug tracker, as this is obviously a bug.

Comment: I tried loading the vim with vim -u NONE -U NONE -N. Problem still persist. I tried it on vim-7.4.2243. In this version they included the indent file of pangloss.